# Ideas for improving old concrete patio on the river?

Tags: concrete, patio

My parent's place in NH has this 30+ year old concrete 12x26 patio jutting out into the water. There has been some settling. Off the end of the patio the water is about 10 feet deep.

[image]

So I'd like some ideas on how to blend in the settling (looks like my father tried it at one time) and making the surface look nice. I'm not too concerned with leveling. I've read about acid staining but I don't want those chemicals in the water.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What does "blend in the settling" mean if you're not concerned with level?

Comment: If it was mine I'd get an estimate for mud-jacking it up to level, and scrape away all the cement patchwork. I'd then consider overlaying quarry tile or porcelain to spiff it up.

Comment: blend in the settling - fill the cracks so when I resurface it will blend in.

Comment: Blend in how? Physically? Aesthetically? What's the goal?

Comment: Main goal is for it to look nice without major replacement. If acid staining is out, maybe some kind of 'topper' such as rubber tiles? I'm just looking for some ideas.

Comment: it's a river, not a pond, unless your dumping barrels of the stuff in, a little acid runoff won't hurt a thing. You might consider a garage-floor treatment based on epoxy (color confetti optional). nice place btw!